# How to choose the correct dimensions for smartphone Android games?

Tags: android, screen, smartphone, dimensions, construct-2

I'm developing an Android game to be played horizontally on smartphones using Construct 2. I am just bit confused on the topic of screen dimensions. There are many different android devices up there which has different dimensions. Is there any standard size i can pick or maybe a proportion that i can follow throughout the process?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why pick one?  Query for the resolution at runtime, and use it.  Anything else will give a bad experience on other devices.

Comment: @GabeSechan : Thanks for your comment. That's indeed a good way to approach this problem. However, as i will be designing the graphics of the game, i need to adjust the sizes of objects in respect to the dimensions. If i am going to query for the resolution, how that will affect the drawn objects? Unless if i am making different versions of the graphics and each single one will suit a range of resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that to use linear layout with weights and let the children views fill these divisions. Also, make sure you have resource files for most resolutions.